# How to find general equation for surface of revolution?

Tags: calculus

If a curve (let's say y=f(x)) revolve around an axis (let's say x-axis), then it would form a surface of revolution.

So is there any way to find the general equation for that surface of revolution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Suppose your function is defined on $[a,b]$ for some $0\le a<b$ and the graph rotates around the $y$-axis. Then the point $(x,y)$ on your graph rotates with radius $x$. A parametrization of your surface (adding a third axis $z$ perpendicular to $x$ and $y$) is then
$$
x=t\cos\theta,\quad y=f(t),\quad z=t\sin\theta
$$
where $t\in[a,b]$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

You can easily adapt it for the case it rotates around the $x$ axis.